# How to join products and their characteristics

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, orm

How to join products and their characteristics

I have two tables.
Product (id, title, price, created_at, updated_at etc) 
and
ProductCharacteristic(id, product_id, sold_quantity, date, craated_at, updated_at etc).

I should show products table (header is product.id, product.title, product.price, sold_quantity) for some period of time and ordered by any fields from header.

And I can't write query

Now I have following query

```
 > current_project.products.includes(:product_characteristics).group('products.id').pluck(:title, 'SUM(product_characteristics.sold_quantity) AS sold_quantity')

(45.4ms) SELECT "products"."title", SUM(product_characteristics.sold_quantity) AS sold_quantity FROM "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_characteristics" ON "product_characteristics"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "products"."project_id" = $1 GROUP BY products.id  [["project_id", 20]]
```

Please help me to write query through orm(to add **where** with dates and ordering) or write raw sql query.

I used **pluck**. It returns array of arrays (not array of hashes). It's no so good of course.

product_characteristics.date field is unique by scope product_id. But please give me two examples (with this condition and without it to satisfy my curiosity).

And I use postgresql and rails 4.2.x
P.S. By the way the ProductCharacteristic table will have a lot of records(mote than one million). Should I use postgresql table partitioning. Can it improve performance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select instead of count in that case, and the property will be accessible as product.sold_quantity

The query becomes

```
products = current_project.products.joins(:product_characteristics).group('products.id').select(:title, 'SUM(product_characteristics.sold_quantity) AS sold_quantity')
```

products.first.sold_quantity # => works

To order, you can just add an order clause

```
products = products.order(id: :asc)
```

or

```
products = products.order(id: :desc)
```

for instance

And for the where

```
products = products.where("created_at > ?", 2.days.ago)
```

for instance.

You can chain sql clauses after the first line, it does not matter cause the query will only be launched when you actually use the retrieved set.
And so you can also do stuff like

```
if params[:foo]
  products = products.order(:id)
end
```

Comment: No. I can't use select

Comment: > current_project.products.includes(:product_characteristics).group('products.id').select(:title, 'SUM(product_characteristics.sold_quantity) AS sold_quantity')
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "product_characteristics"
LINE 1: SELECT "products"."title", SUM(product_characteristics.sold_...
                                       ^
: SELECT "products"."title", SUM(product_characteristics.sold_quantity) AS sold_quantity FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."project_id" = $1 GROUP BY products.id
=> #<Product::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x3fd8e44ad894>

Comment: Oh yeah, try to use joins instead of includes

Comment: Okay, I use joins with LEFT OUTER JOIN, but how can I order by sold_quantity?

Comment: Oh sorry, I used symbol(order(sold_quantity: :desc)), it works only with string. Okay. Thank you so much. I should use select instead of pluck and everything will be good. I tried using it before asking, but it returns the result like [#<Product id: 15043, title: "sadas">,
 #<Product id: 14426, title: "asdasdsa">, and I thought that I can get sold_quantity. So I asked here.

Comment: Excuse me, one more question: what do you think about postgresql table partitioning (The last sentence from my initial question)